# Identity Server 4 : Custom OIDC login callback to store tokens in a store

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, access-token, openid-connect, blazor

I'm currently building a Blazor app that needs authentication and retrieve acces_token to access an API. I'm also using refresh_token to avoid user relogin when browsing.

My current way to manage it is to register a custom `httpClient` in dependency injection system, retrieve `HttpContext` to check for access_token and if not good, call manually idsrv4 to retrieve new access & refresh tokens

The main issue is that by doing so, I cannot write into `httpContext` the new values (response has already begin) so I'll have to do it everytime, losing advantages of token lifetime.

My goal is to store all user informations & token informations within a custom store. To do so, I'll have to handle the point when tokens are retrieved, but I can't find a god place to fit in as callback ?

I've already tried the `Events` property within the `AddOpenIdConnect` options, but it doesn't seems any of them can fit my needs ?

Where can I put my custom callback logic after login ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get and store the access token after client app get the access token , you can use `OnTokenResponseReceived` event :

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{

    OnTokenResponseReceived = ctx =>
    {
        var accessToken = ctx.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken;

        var idToken = ctx.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much !